# CefSharp behaves slow in Revit 2021 compared to older version

Tags: cefsharp, revit-api

I have been working with Revit and CefSharp since Revit 2017,

Since Revit for 2017 and 2018 did not have in-built CefSharp, I was using the latest version of CefSharp to create plugins UI.

But from Revit 2019 onwards since Revit itself loaded the CefSharp there were fixed versions that needed to be followed like (Revit 2019 supported 57 and Revit 2020 and 2021 supports 65.0.1).

But in Revit 2021, the UI and data transfer between Revit and CefSharp (UI) seems to be very slow.
The UI, c# code and CefSharp version is same for Revit 2020 and works very well for Revit 2020 but is very slow for Revit 2021.

```
            this.browser.Address = "http://<online_path>";
            this.browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("revit", new BoundObject(m_externalEvents, this.browser, this), true);
```

The above code is used in 2020 and 2021 for Registering the object.

Can someone guide me the correct way to use CefSharp for Revit 2021 or what additional is required for Revit 2021 to improve the performance like Revit 2020.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed the same & have taken the approach outlined here:

https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/04/set-floor-level-and-use-ipc-for-disentanglement.html#5

Don't use the same CEFShap version as Revit.  Run the browser in a separate process & use IPC to communicate between Revit & the browser process.  This allows you to use any version of CEFSharp.  I share this separate process with all versions of Revit.